# Haskell -- check last item of list

Tags: list, haskell, uppercase

I need to check if last element of list is uppercase
For example `"abc"` -- `False`, `"abC"` -- `True`

That's what I tried

```
checkLast :: [a] -> Bool
checkLast [] = False
checkLast [x] = if isUpper x then True else False
checkLast (x:xs) = if isUpper last then True else False
```

Comment: A couple of things. **1** `if isUpper x then True else False` is the same as `isUpper x`. **2** Have a second look at the final case. Where do you get `last` from? Why is `x:xs` unused?

Answer (score 4):

Think recursively. `checkLast (x:xs)` is just checking `checkLast xs`:

```
checkLast :: [Char] -> Bool
checkLast [] = False
checkLast [x] = isUpper x
checkLast (x:xs) = checkLast xs
```

Note that since you are using `isUpper` to check strings, it makes more sense that the type should be `[Char]`, not `[a]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of recursion like the other answers demonstrate. But you can also use builtins to construct such a function.

Two relevant functions here are `null :: [a] -> Bool` which checks whether a list is empty, and `last :: [a] -> a` which obtains the last element.

So now we can construct a function:

```
import Data.Char(isUpper)

checkLast :: [Char] -> Bool
checkLast l = not (null l) && isUpper (last l)
```

So here we state that `checkLast` is `True` if the list `l` is not empty (`not (null l)`); and the last element is an uppercase character `isUpper (last l)`.

This will probably be a bit faster than the recursive functions, since we only test the `[]` case once (in `null`). `last` checks only two cases: `[x]` and `(x:xs)` so we save on `[]` checks.

Of course these functions work with recursion, but it is sometimes useful to look for helper functions such that a function is almost self explaining: here the functions says: "*A list `l` is `checkLast` if it is not empty, and the last element is an uppercase*".

Comment: I got the impression that it's an assignment, given the slightly contrived question and the way the OP approached it.

Comment: I think it's better to use total functions than to guard partial functions.

Answer (score 1):

A fixed version with comments:

```
import Data.Char (isUpper)

checkLast :: [Char] -> Bool      -- it cannot be [a]: use of isUpper already limits possible type to [Char]
checkLast [] = False
checkLast [x] = isUpper x        -- the if .. can be shorter
checkLast (x:xs) = checkLast xs  -- drop first char and look at rest of string
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to avoid explicit recursion, if you wish to do so, is probably to use a fold:

```
lastMay :: [a] -> Maybe a
lastMay = foldl' (\_ x -> Just x) Nothing

checkLast = maybe True isUpper . lastMay
```

Comment: This is also a terrible solution since you needlessly have to import `Data.Maybe` package just to implement this simple task. It's totally not needed. See my annexed answer.

Comment: @Redu, the only non-prelude function I used is `foldl'`. But base imports are benign anyway.

Answer (score -2):

You may also do as follows without any recursion

```
import Data.Char

checkLast :: String -> Bool
checkLast = (&&) <$> not . null <*> isUpper . head . reverse
```

The applicative operator, `<*>` is an ideal tool to feed a common parameter (the input string here) to two different functions like `not . null` and `isUpper . head . reverse` and then to make an operation `(&&)` on their result.

As per @dfeuer's comment I just would like to annex the following solution for a better performance. You don't need to import any other package than `Data.Char`

```
import Data.Char

checkLast :: String -> Bool
checkLast [] = False
checkLast cs = isUpper $ foldr1 seq cs
```

Comment: This, however, is a terrible solution. Aside from being complicated, it also builds a reversed string only to look at one element and throw the rest away. It's terribly inefficient.

Comment: @dfeuer How is this code snippet complicated really? This is a very basic pattern in Haskell. As per inefficiency i believe it is not inefficient in time complexity but yes... space wise one could use `last` in the place of `head . reverse`.

Comment: Using the `Applicative` instance for functions strikes me as obfuscating more than clarifying in this case.